# Remove all lines where password = ze5fze56f4

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have 90k registered users on my website, and I'd like to remove all users that have "ze5fze56f4" as password.

I made this script, but it always done without removing any line and so saying "0 users removed".

```
<?php

require "includes/db.php";

$x = 0;

for($i = 0; $i < 91000; $i++){

    $SQLcheckPassword = $odb -> prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE ID = :i");
    $SQLcheckPassword -> execute(array(":i" => $i));
    $SQLgetPassword   = $SQLcheckPassword -> fetchColumn();

    if(strpos($SQLgetPassword, "ze5fze56f4")){

        $x++;

        $SQLdeleteUser = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = :i");
        $SQLdeleteUser -> execute(array(":i" => $i));

    }

}

die("$x users removed");

?>
```

I don't understand why it's not working, but I know I'm not doing it by the simpliest way.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are you really storing passwords in clear? What's your website so I can stay away from it because it is not respecting basic security practices...

Comment: Why not `DELETE FROM users WHERE password LIKE '%ze5fze56f4%'`? And never store passwords in clear! Use Hashing to store passwords.

Comment: `if(strpos($SQLgetPassword, "ze5fze56f4") !== false){`

Comment: No, passwords are crypted in MD5 but few days ago I made a mistake with a for loop and it created lot of users with this password, and now I want to remove all of them.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Because I want to count them :)

Comment: Don't you dare use md5 for passwords.  Your site is beyond vulnerable lol

Comment: Thanks, I used `if(strpos($SQLgetPassword, "ze5fze56f4") !== false)` and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `$SQLgetPassword` is `"ze5fze56f4"`, `strpos($SQLgetPassword, "ze5fze56f4")` will return `0` (the beginning of the string). `0` is interpreted as `FALSE` in boolean context, so the `if` statement will never be entered. Replacing the `strpos` with a plain old equality check should work, but frankly, I don't think this is the right way to go. Instead of reinventing the wheel, just let the database do the heavy lifting for you:

```
$SQLdeleteUser = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE password = :s");
$SQLdeleteUser -> execute(array(":s" => "ze5fze56f4"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I used `if(strpos($SQLgetPassword, "ze5fze56f4") !== false)` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the script, just run a single SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE password="ze5fze56f4";
```

(Note:  **Always** make backups before running big commands like this.  I obviously don't have access to your database and cannot test or confirm this ahead of time, so before you nuke your users, at least run it as a SELECT or something.)

The next thing you should do is stop storing passwords.  Store hashes with salts instead.  Otherwise, your site is insecure by default and your poor security practices are going to get accounts compromised, on your site and others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should simply try

DELETE FROM users WHERE password="ze5fze56f4"

Answer (score 0):

You can try simply as following

```
$SQLdeleteUser = $odb -> prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE password = :s");
$SQLdeleteUser -> execute(array(":s" => "ze5fze56f4"));
```

Comment: it should be `WHERE password = :s`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I used `if(strpos($SQLgetPassword, "ze5fze56f4") !== false)` and it worked.